# In here, the data successfully Stored message shows. But data is not showing in the mongo DB database. What is the trouble with it?

Tags: frontend, mern

In here, the data successfully Stored message shows. But data is not showing in the mongo DB database. What is the trouble with it?

I'm creating a simple cruds application using React.js and node.js, connecting using Axios. I use DB as mongo DB. This is the data insertion react.js file.

```
  const onSubmit = () => {
    

    const data = {
      name: name,
      age: age,
      city: cityArray,
    };

    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/student", data).then((res) => {
      if (res.data.success) {
        alert("Added Succes");
        window.location = "/";
        setAge("");
        setCity("");
        setName("");
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the Exact Error?
Did you Implement the PreventDefault function?
if not, please use the following code,

```
e.prventDefault();
```

in the onSubmit function ,do the following changes

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    
e.prventDefault();

    const data = {
      name: name,
      age: age,
      city: cityArray,
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this you can get clear idea

```
import React from 'react';
    import {
      BrowserRouter,
      Routes,
      Route,
    } from "react-router-dom";
    import AddPosts from './components/AddPosts.jsx';
    import Posts from './components/Posts.jsx';
    import UpdatePosts from './components/UpdatePosts.jsx';
    import UserRegister from './components/UserRegister';
    import UserLogin from './components/UserLogin';
    
    
    export function App() {
      return(
       <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={ <UserLogin/>}/>
        <Route path="/user/register" element={ <UserRegister/>}/>
          <Route path="/add" element={<AddPosts/>}></Route>    
          <Route path="/view" element={<Posts/>}></Route>  
          <Route path="/update/:id" element={<UpdatePosts/>}></Route>
          
          </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
      );
    }
```